# Linq to xml, when child nodes meet a certain condition

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

Let's say that I have the next xml:

```
<Report>
<File id="1">
    <Variables>
            <Variable id="1" name="integer"> 1 </Variable>
            <Variable id="1" name="string"> x </Variable>
    </Variables>
</File>
<File id="2">
    <Variables>
            <Variable id="2" name="integer"> 1 </Variable>
            <Variable id="2" name="string"> x </Variable>
    </Variables>
</File>
<File id="3">
    <Variables>
            <Variable id="3" name="integer"> 1 </Variable>
            <Variable id="3" name="string"> y </Variable>
    </Variables>
</File>
```

How can I get all Files in which variable string is "x"?

Note linq to xml vb or c# but vb is preferred

Comment: Please when asking questions show what you've tried/did not work instead of filling your post with thank you/searched alot unrelated text.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've already loaded your XML to `XDocument` instance, you can do following:

```
var files = from f in xDoc.Root.Elements("File")
            where f.Element("Variables")
                   .Elements("Variable")
                   .Any(v => (string)v.Attribute == "string" &&
                             (string)v == "x")
            select f;
```

or using equivalent Method based query:

```
var files = xDoc.Root.Elements("File")
                     .Where(f => f.Element("Variables")
                                  .Elements("Variable")
                                  .Any(v => (string)v.Attribute == "string" &&
                                            (string)v == "x"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following xml:

```
Dim xml = <Report>
                <File id="1">
                    <Variables>
                            <Variable id="1" name="integer">1</Variable>
                            <Variable id="1" name="string">x</Variable>
                    </Variables>
                </File>
                <File id="2">
                    <Variables>
                            <Variable id="2" name="integer">1</Variable>
                            <Variable id="2" name="string">x</Variable>
                    </Variables>
                </File>
                <File id="3">
                    <Variables>
                            <Variable id="3" name="integer">1</Variable>
                            <Variable id="3" name="string">y</Variable>
                    </Variables>
                </File>
                </Report>
```

you can either use Linq:

```
Dim result = xml.<File> _
                .Where(Function(file) file.<Variables>.<Variable> _
                  .Any(Function(variable) variable.@name = "string" AndAlso 
                                          variable.Value = "x"))
```

or, shorter, query the nodes with an XPath-Expression:

```
Dim doc = New XmlDocument() ' Use XmlDocument instead of XElement '
doc.LoadXml(xml.ToString())
Dim result = doc.SelectNodes("/Report/File[Variables/Variable[@name='string' and text()='x']]")
```